# Wordpress blog pagination error

Tags: wordpress, pagination

An the bottom of the blog page of my WordPress site, there are numbers for pagination.

Assume my initial blog post page is `https://example.com/blog`

When I click number '2' to view more posts. My url changed as `https://example.com/blogpage/2`

However if i manually enter the url as `https://example.com/blog/page/2` it goes to the second page of blog posts.

I only get this error when i am in page 1. When 
I am in page 2 or page 3, the pagination links work fine

How can I correct this issue?

index.php file contains this code

```
<?php
global $wp_query, $wpl_exe_wp;
get_header();
get_template_part('part', 'breadcrumbs');

$style = $wpl_exe_wp->get_option('blog_archive_layout', 'system_layouts');

$read_more_text = $wpl_exe_wp->get_option('blog_read_more_text', 'system_layouts');

if( is_author() ) {
    $style = $wpl_exe_wp->get_option('author_archive_layout', 'system_layouts');
    $read_more_text = $wpl_exe_wp->get_option('author_read_more_text', 'system_layouts');
}
if( is_search() ) {
    $read_more_text = $wpl_exe_wp->get_option('search_read_more_text', 'system_layouts');
    if( get_query_var('post_type') == 'product' ) {

    } else {
        $style = $wpl_exe_wp->get_option('search_layout', 'system_layouts');
    }
}
if( is_post_type_archive('wproto_portfolio') || is_tax( 'wproto_portfolio_category' ) ) {
    $style = $wpl_exe_wp->get_option('portfolio_archive_layout', 'system_layouts');
    $read_more_text = $wpl_exe_wp->get_option('portfolio_read_more_text', 'system_layouts');
}
```

?>

```
<section class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="<?php echo wpl_exe_wp_front::content_classes( true ) . ' wproto-primary-content-area'; ?>">

            <?php if( is_author() && $wpl_exe_wp->get_option('author_page_display_info', 'system_layouts') ): ?>
                <!--
                    ABOUT AUTHOR INFO
                -->
                <?php wpl_exe_wp_front::about_author(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( is_post_type_archive('wproto_portfolio') || is_tax( 'wproto_portfolio_category' ) ): ?>
                <!--
                    PORTFOLIO POSTS
                -->
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[wproto_portfolio read_more_text="' . esc_attr( $read_more_text ) . '" use_wp_query="1" posts_per_page="' . get_option('posts_per_page') . '" order_by="date" sort_by="DESC" style="' . esc_attr( $style ) . '" display_pagination="1" pagination_style="numeric_with_prev_next"]'); ?>

            <?php else: ?>
                <!--
                    POSTS
                -->

                <?php
                    $term_description = term_description();
                    if( $term_description <> '' ) {
                        echo wp_kses_post( $term_description );
                    } 
                ?>

                <?php echo do_shortcode('[wproto_blog read_more_text="' . esc_attr( $read_more_text ) . '" use_wp_query="1" posts_per_page="' . get_option('posts_per_page') . '" order_by="date" sort_by="DESC" style="' . esc_attr( $style ) . '" display_pagination="1" pagination_style="numeric_with_prev_next"]'); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do in first page load displays the posts ?

Comment: can you post your pagination code?

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli yes it shows posts in first page

Comment: @vel I didn't add any custom code. it's the default wp blog posts page

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: @LakinduNanayakkara while you open the page 1 ..what sort of result does it displays ?

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli it shows all the posts

Comment: @LakinduNanayakkara then i think your pagination code is not working good.. can you show some code that you have written for better understanding ?

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli i didn't write any custom code for pagination. Where can i find the default pagination code?

Comment: @vel EXE theme, a purchased theme from themeforest

Comment: you should share some code

Comment: @vel sure, tell me where can i find the code for pagination. Then I can post that code.

Comment: do you have single.php file?

Comment: @vel i added the code in single.php

Comment: you pagination displaying like next and previous type?

Comment: @vel no as numbers

Comment: then it is not in single.php

Comment: @vel yeah... is there any possible file.. ?

Comment: check this file content-page.php?

Comment: @vel it doesn't have a single-page.php. there was a page.php. i added the content of it

Comment: sorry, this script also not containing pagination code

Comment: @vel this include a function call for wp_link_pages() Definition of that function is available at wp-includes/post-template.php . Will it contain the pagination code?

Comment: wp_link_pages is for previous and next post

Comment: check this code `the_posts_pagination( array(
    'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',
   ) );` in index.php file

Comment: i added the code of index.php

Comment: Your theme structure is something different I think. Not possible to check this. Need more info